# Can not convert HiddenField to Int32

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I am having a problem with data type conversion that I just can figure out

```
 HiddenField hfFriendId = item.FindControl("hfFriendId") as HiddenField;
 Int32 FriendId = Convert.ToInt32(hfFriendId.Value);
```

I need to use FriendId as and int32 in the following

```
UserInfo TargetUser = UserController.GetUserById(PortalSettings.PortalId, FriendId);
```

as both args are expected to be int32. 
When I debug this 'TargetUser' is null.

What might the problem be?

Comment: Is there any UserInfo available for the parameters passed ? What is the value of `FriendId` when you pass the argument ?

Comment: check if the value of `hfFriendId.Value` is empty (or null) or not. `Int32 FriendId=0; if(hfFriendId.Value!=""){ FriendId = Convert.ToInt32(hfFriendId.Value); else {FriendId =0;}}`

Comment: That's the thing, FriendId it is populated with a value

Comment: Is the name of the field correct (hfFriendId)?

Comment: watching hfFriendId in debug I can see it has value. also when I look at UserInfo TargetUser = UserController.GetUserById(PortalSettings.PortalId, FriendId); I can see there that FriendId has a value but in the eind TargetUser remains null

Comment: @MarkHollas If it has a valid value then post the details for the `GetUserById` methos, maybe something wrong in there

Comment: Here is something odd. If I do this Int32 FriendId = 100; the TargetUser is populated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not sure of the value available in the hiddenfield then instead of using

```
Int32 FriendId = Convert.ToInt32(hfFriendId.Value);
```

Try

```
int FriendId = int.Parse(hfFriendId.Value); // will throw exception if parse fails
```

or Better

```
int FriendId ;
if(int.TryParse(hfFriendId.Value, out FriendId))
     //get userinfo
```

Also it could be an issue with your `UserController.GetUserById` method in case the Convert gets the value parsed and is not returning zero.

Comment: I am using a hidden field in a asp:listView itemtemplate to pass value back to the code behind. HiddenField by nature is a string. I wonder, is there similar way I could pass the value back as an int?

Comment: What you suggested is a valid answer to my question. The issue however was self produced. the UserInfo object needs not just an int data type but also a valid userid! Somehow my test data was item was not a valid user id.